# mono - Mono.Options.dll not found

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm trying to run a small C# application which parses its command-line arguments using Mono.Options. I added the following line to my `.csproj`:

```
<Reference Include="Mono.Options" />
```

and it compiles fine. However, when trying to actually run the application, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Options, Version=0.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Options, Version=0.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Options, Version=0.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Options, Version=0.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
```

What am I doing wrong? `locate Mono.Options` shows the following:

```
/home/martin/.cache/MonoDevelop-5.0/DerivedData/Mono.Options.dll-f8111709
/home/martin/.cache/MonoDevelop-5.0/DerivedData/Mono.Options.dll-f8111709/0
/home/martin/.cache/MonoDevelop-5.0/DerivedData/Mono.Options.dll-f8111709/0/assembly.data
/home/martin/.cache/MonoDevelop-5.0/DerivedData/Mono.Options.dll-f8111709/0/assembly.tag
/home/martin/.cache/MonoDevelop-5.0/DerivedData/Mono.Options.dll-f8111709/0/data.xml
/usr/lib/mono/4.5-api/Mono.Options.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5.1-api/Mono.Options.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Mono.Options.dll
```

(I'm not using Visual Studio, monodevelop or any such IDEs, so please don't tell me to click some magic button or tick an option on a menu).